# How to get Jsonarray from Jsonarray if they dont have jsonobject in android

Tags: android, json

How to get jsonarray from jsonarray?

code which i have tried.

```
              for(loop) 
             List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        JSONArray responses = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length(); i++) {
                            stringList.add(responses.getString(i));
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    i want to get this json:


         [
            "maj",
                [
                   "maja salvador",
                   "maje",
                   "majboos",
                   "major lazer",
                   "majili",
                   "majid al futtaim",
                   "majorca",
                   "majestic",
                   "major",
                   "majnoon qahwa"
                  ]
        ]
```

here is the link you can try.
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=maj

Comment: sorry your question is not clear, you want to get jsonarry for json array?

Comment: amm i just want get above response in my listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one like below

```
 try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("YOUR_REPONSE");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            if (jsonArray.get(i).toString().contains("[")) {
                //json array

                JSONArray innerJSSONArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray.getString(i));
                for (int j = 0; j < innerJSSONArray.length(); j++) {

                    Log.e("JSONARRAY", innerJSSONArray.getString(i));

                }


            } else {
                Log.e("WITH_OUT_JSONARRAY", jsonArray.getString(i));

            }

        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: let me check.:)

Comment: I have updated the code...Use "contains" in place of the "equalsIgnoreCase"

Comment: one more question bro why link i mentioned everytime download response file instead of showing me on browser.in postman its working fine

Comment: I have updated the solution, now it will work for you, Have look on it i use the "getString" instead of the "get"..Let me know in case of concern..

Answer (score 1):

You can parse data using like bellow solution

```
JSONArray jsonArray;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData); //Set your mixed data
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Object object = jsonArray.get(i);
                if (object instanceof JSONArray) { // Check is it array or object 
                    JSONArray jsonSubArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    for (int k = 0; k < jsonSubArray.length(); k++) {
                        //Whatever you want to parse Key value object
                    }
                } else {
//                This is the JSON object so you can access directly key value
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: for checking JSON contains particular jsonArray key, you can use "has"
and for you json data you can try

try {
    // jsonString is a string variable that holds the JSON 
    JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
        int value=itemArray.getInt(i);
        Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Right, for the key exist or not you can use has or for compare you can use instanceof..